# Scrollbar + LinearLayout + GridView .. GridView not scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-scrollbar

My Current Layout is

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:fillViewport="true" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/llGridToday"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:visibility="gone">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/gridframe" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/calender" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtDateToday"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="28" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:text="Today"
                    android:textColor="#000" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridToday"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/FrameLayout1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:numColumns="3" >
            </GridView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/llGridTomorrow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/llGridToday"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:visibility="gone">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/gridframe" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/calender" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtDateTomorrow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="28" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:text="Tomorrow"
                    android:textColor="#000" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridTomorrow"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/FrameLayout1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:numColumns="3" >
            </GridView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/llGridMonth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/llGridTomorrow"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:visibility="gone">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/gridframe" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="This Month"
                    android:textColor="#000" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridMonth"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/FrameLayout1"
                android:numColumns="3" android:stretchMode="columnWidth">
            </GridView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This `Layout` contains three `GridViews`.
I am making Parent `RelativeLayout`s of `GridViews` visible with logic and adding inflated `ImageView` + `TextView` to `GridView`.

Its looking fine. but no scrolling is there.

Comment: Putting scrollable things in scrollable things like this infrequently works. `ScrollView` in particular rarely works out of the box with things that scroll vertically, like `GridView`.

Comment: gridviews are only scrolable (by default) only when its flowing out of screen....then you may think of using a holder to hold data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah what is the point of having three different `GridView`. Just Create a single `GridView` as parent and have an separate layout for `GridItem` so you can style it the way you need to.

**UPDATE**

isn't something like this will work for you???

one layout with following code

```
        <GridView 
            android:id="@+id/gridTomorrow" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/FrameLayout1" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:numColumns="3" > 
        </GridView>
```

and another Layout for `GridItem`

```
        <FrameLayout   
            android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"   
            android:layout_width="match_parent"   
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"   
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >   

            <ImageView   
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"   
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
                android:src="@drawable/gridframe" />   

            <FrameLayout   
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
                android:layout_gravity="right"   
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"   
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"   
                android:background="@drawable/calender" >   

                <TextView   
                    android:id="@+id/txtDateTomorrow"   
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
                    android:layout_gravity="center"   
                    android:gravity="center"   
                    android:text="28" />   
            </FrameLayout>   

            <TextView   
                android:id="@+id/TextView02"   
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"   
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"   
                android:text="Tomorrow"   
                android:textColor="#000" />   
        </FrameLayout>
```

using an `GridAdapter` `Inflate` your `GridItems` into grid

Comment: According to the Current Logic.. Both the Above RelativeLayouts containing 2 gridViews are Visibly gone.. but 3 gridviews are must as per functionality as I mentioned below in Macarse's comment's reply

Comment: I am having hard time understanding logic behind the layout @Vishal has posted. Does somebody else make any sense out of it???

Comment: please explain your functionality requiremnts so I can get to understand the logic. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need three different `GridView`.

Try making `GridView` the parent and adding the rest of the `View` items as `GridView`'s headers.

Comment: @Macarase..  All the Three Views are for different types of data and Click handling of that data are also different for all the 3 gridview items.. So I thought that is must to have 3 diff. gridviews..

Comment: @Vishal: Try adding every type in the same `GridView`.